# how to connect ionic 2 Application with backend service?

Tags: android, ionic2, backend

this is my first week in starting in ionic 2 application for android 
and i want to connect my app to a online database.

using [Backend](https://www.backand.com)

i already have my application but the documentation in backend website dose not help me .

thanks in advance.

**note** : i can use any other service

Comment: you mean _backand service_?

Comment: yes
i need fetch row from online database
insert new row 
delete row 
and so on 
i just need the steps to do thing like thi